# Could a machine be built that allows you to talk on different frequencies?

Tags: internal-consistency, communication

Could there be a machine that allows you to talk on different frequencies like the radio wave level or is this magitech? Also would it be an invaluable tool for spies?

Comment: We might be misunderstanding your question.  A radio allows you to talk on radio frequencies.  Are you talking about a piece of equipment? (answer: yes, and none of it is magic tech) or are you talking about the literal ability to speak using frequencies other than the audible, or speak electromagnetically rather than using air pressure?  Please note, there is a considerable difference between a 1Khz electromagetic wave (radio) and a 1Khz audible frequency (sound).  You can hear the later, but not the former.

Comment: this is a really wierd question because its a simple yes that anyone should know.

Comment: This question is rather unclear, could the OP please elaborate? And make the title more relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to be able to talk directly with someone on a frequency that is entirely between the two of you. No one else should be able to access that conversation without being on the same frequency. Is that what you hope to achieve?

If so, the several versions of the machine do exist, and it starts with the humble walkie-talkie, climbing all the way up the tech ladder to the smartphone of today. Ta-dah!

Comment: You can't have a (broadcast) frequency that is entirely between two points.  Anyone with a proper receiver can listen in.  If you want to keep a conversation private, you either need to encode or encrypt it (which can be as simple as using a different language, like the WWII Code Talkers), or use spread-spectrum technologies, so the eavesdropper must know exactly which frequencies to listen to.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about a radio? It has a very large range of frequencies. If you mean a non-radio wave frequency, then also yes. Your TV remote or other similar controllers often use infrared light, which is a significantly higher frequency light wave. There isn't really anything stopping you from going to higher frequencies. but they have increasing energy requirements to produce, and are more likely to be blocked by obstacles.